Closed form: show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{(n+1)4^n}=\zeta(2) $

Let $a_n$ be the sequence defined via
$$ a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n{2n \choose {n-k}}\frac{1+(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2}$$
then prove that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{(n+1)4^n}=\frac{\pi^2}{6} $$

I tried simplifying $a_n$ first, but in the end the best I got is an expression according to Wolfram, using Hypergeometric functions:
$$a_n={2n\choose {n-1}}\left(_4F_3\left({{1,1,1,1-n}\atop{2,2,2+n}};1\right)+\  _4F_3\left({{1,1,1,1-n}\atop{2,2,2+n}};-1\right)\right) $$
I didn't manage to simplify it further. This work does not seem helpful, since Hypergeometric functions $_4F_3$ are no easier to work with.
At this point I'm stuck. I believe representing $a_n$ with an integral would simplify the problem, but didn't manage to achieve it for now.

Are you sure this is correct? Numerically Ive tested it and it doesnt seem to be correct? Also I have a somewhat shotty proof that it cant be correct. Numerical it seems closer to $\zeta(2)/2$

To be slow, it is !

@AidanR.S. $\zeta(2)$ seems to be correct, although it converges extremely slow. WolframAlpha is able to sum up to $~500$ terms, leading to $\simeq 1.5$, so $\zeta(2)/2$ is not the right answer

I think that if this question doesn't get an answer after several days of posting it here on MSE you should post it on MO

What is the context of this question? Is it from a text book or arose in your personal research or some other source?

@Zima looking over my code for the series I relized Im an idiot. Instead of doing $1+(-1)^{k+1}$ I was just skipping even k but I forgot to include the multiple of 2 that comes along with the odd k hence off by a fector of 2 and I was getting $\zeta (2)/2$.

@JamesArathoon I got it a side result while evaluating an integral, so I was looking for a direct evaluation

Have you tried inverting the order of summation? Wolfram Alpha gives a formula in terms of ${}4F_3()$ hypergeometric functions for $\sum{n=k+1}^m\dfrac{2n\choose n-k}{4^n(n+1)}$ but can't seem to do the $m\to\infty$ limit; I feel like there may be a relatively clean closed form available there, though...

@StevenStadnicki The lower index should be $n=k$ instead of $n=k+1$.

@ТymaGaidash, see my answer, I have the same thing in my first term. I have also evaluated to a few more terms


Let $\mathcal{S}$ denote the sum of the following infinite series:
$$\mathcal{S}:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{\left(n+1\right)4^{n}},$$
where
$$a_{n}:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{n-k}\frac{1+(-1)^{k+1}}{k^{2}};~~~\small{n\in\mathbb{N}}.$$
We first show that the series can be reduced to an integral as
$$\mathcal{S}=\frac43\zeta{\left(2\right)}+4\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2x\ln{\left(1-x+x^{2}\right)}}{1+x^{2}}.$$
We then evaluate the integral using Feynman's trick to obtain the conjectured value of $\mathcal{S}$.

Consider the following basic integration formula
$$\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}z\,z^{k-1}=\frac{y^{k}}{k};~~~\small{k\in\mathbb{N}\land y\in\mathbb{R}}.$$
It follows that
$$\frac{x^{k}}{k^{2}}=\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}z\,\frac{z^{k}}{yz};~~~\small{k\in\mathbb{N}\land x\in\mathbb{R}}.$$
For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we can then express $a_{n}$ as a double integral as follows:
$$\begin{align}
a_{n}
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{n-k}\frac{1+(-1)^{k+1}}{k^{2}}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{n-k}\left[1+(-1)^{k+1}\right]\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}z\,\frac{z^{k}}{yz}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}z\,\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{n-k}\left[1+(-1)^{k+1}\right]y^{-1}z^{k-1}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}z\,y^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{n-k}\left[z^{k-1}+\left(-z\right)^{k-1}\right]\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}z\,y^{-1}\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{n-k}z^{k-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{n-k}\left(-z\right)^{k-1}\right].\\
\end{align}$$

Recall the basic definition of the Gauss hypergeometric function ${_2F_1}$ for real parameters $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}\land c\notin\mathbb{Z}_{\le0}$ and complex argument $z\in\mathbb{C}\land|z|\le1$ by the power series
$${_2F_1}{\left(a,b;c;z\right)}:=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(a\right)_{n}\,\left(b\right)_{n}\,z^{n}}{\left(c\right)_{n}\,n!};~~~\small{|z|<1\lor\left(|z|=1\land c-a-b>0\right)},$$
where the Pochhammer symbol $\left(r\right)_{n}$ is defined for $r\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}$ by
$$\left(r\right)_{n}=
\begin{cases}
1;&n=0,\\
\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(r+k-1\right);&n>0.\\
\end{cases}$$
The series terminates if $a$ is a nonpositive integer, in which case the Gauss hypergeometric function reduces to a polynomial:
$${_2F_1}{\left(-m,b;c;z\right)}:=\sum_{n=0}^{m}\left(-1\right)^{n}\binom{m}{n}\frac{\left(b\right)_{n}\,z^{n}}{\left(c\right)_{n}};~~~\small{m\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}}.$$
For $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}\land0<b<c$ and $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus(1,\infty)$, the Gauss hypergeometric function can be expressed as an integral through Euler's integration formula:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{t^{b-1}\left(1-t\right)^{c-b-1}}{\left(1-zt\right)^{a}}=\operatorname{B}{\left(b,c-b\right)}\,{_2F_1}{\left(a,b;c;z\right)};~~~\small{z\neq1\lor\left(z=1\land c-a-b>0\right)}.$$
Using the machinery of hypergeometric functions, we can then show that for $n\in\mathbb{N}\land z\in\mathbb{C}\land|z|\le1$,
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{n-k}z^{k-1}
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(2n)!}{(n-k)!\,(n+k)!}\,z^{k-1}\\
&=\frac{(2n)!}{(n-1)!\,(n+1)!}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!\,(n-k)!}\cdot\frac{(n+1)!\,(k-1)!\,z^{k-1}}{(n+k)!}\\
&=\binom{2n}{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{\left(1\right)_{k-1}\,z^{k-1}}{\left(n+2\right)_{k-1}}\\
&=\binom{2n}{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}\frac{\left(1\right)_{k}\,z^{k}}{\left(n+2\right)_{k}}\\
&=\binom{2n}{n-1}\,{_2F_1}{\left(1-n,1;n+2;-z\right)}\\
&=\left(n+1\right)\binom{2n}{n-1}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\left(1-t\right)^{n}\left(1+zt\right)^{n-1}\\
&=n\binom{2n}{n}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\left(1-t\right)^{n}\left(1+zt\right)^{n-1}.\\
\end{align}$$

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we can then write $a_{n}$ as
$$\begin{align}
a_{n}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}z\,y^{-1}\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{n-k}z^{k-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{n-k}\left(-z\right)^{k-1}\right]\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\int_{z}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,y^{-1}\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{n-k}z^{k-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{n-k}\left(-z\right)^{k-1}\right]\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\,\left[-\ln{\left(z\right)}\right]\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{n-k}z^{k-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{n-k}\left(-z\right)^{k-1}\right]\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\,\left[-\ln{\left(z\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~\times\left[n\binom{2n}{n}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\left(1-t\right)^{n}\left(1+zt\right)^{n-1}+n\binom{2n}{n}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\left(1-t\right)^{n}\left(1-zt\right)^{n-1}\right]\\
&=n\binom{2n}{n}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\,\left[-\ln{\left(z\right)}\right]\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\left(1-t\right)^{n}\left[\left(1+zt\right)^{n-1}+\left(1-zt\right)^{n-1}\right]\\
&=\binom{2n}{n}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,n\left(1-t\right)^{n}\left[\left(1+zt\right)^{n-1}+\left(1-zt\right)^{n-1}\right]\left[-\ln{\left(z\right)}\right]\\
&=\binom{2n}{n}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\,n\left(1-t\right)^{n}\left[\left(1+zt\right)^{n-1}+\left(1-zt\right)^{n-1}\right]\left[-\ln{\left(z\right)}\right]\\
&=\binom{2n}{n}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\left(1-t\right)^{n}\left[-n\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\,\left(1+zt\right)^{n-1}\ln{\left(z\right)}-n\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\,\left(1-zt\right)^{n-1}\ln{\left(z\right)}\right]\\
&=\binom{2n}{n}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\left(1-t\right)^{n}\left[\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\,\frac{\left(1+zt\right)^{n}-1}{zt}-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\,\frac{\left(1-zt\right)^{n}-1}{zt}\right];~~~\small{I.B.P.}\\
&=\binom{2n}{n}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\left(1-t\right)^{n}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\,\frac{\left(1+zt\right)^{n}-\left(1-zt\right)^{n}}{zt}.\\
\end{align}$$

Define the auxiliary function $f{(x)}$ by the series
$$f{\left(x\right)}:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}\,x^{n}}{\left(n+1\right)4^{n}};~~~\small{|x|\le1}.$$
For $|x|\le1$, we find
$$\begin{align}
x\left[1+f{\left(x\right)}\right]
&=x\left[1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}\,x^{n}}{\left(n+1\right)4^{n}}\right]\\
&=x+x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}\,x^{n}}{\left(n+1\right)4^{n}}\\
&=x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}\,x^{n}}{\left(n+1\right)4^{n}}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}\,x^{n+1}}{\left(n+1\right)4^{n}}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^{n}}\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\,y^{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}\operatorname{B}{\left(n+\frac12,\frac12\right)}\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\,y^{n}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}y^{n}\operatorname{B}{\left(n+\frac12,\frac12\right)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}y^{n}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,u^{n-1/2}\left(1-u\right)^{-1/2}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}y^{n}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{u^{n}}{\sqrt{u\left(1-u\right)}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{y^{n}u^{n}}{\sqrt{u\left(1-u\right)}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{1}{\left(1-yu\right)\sqrt{u\left(1-u\right)}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y}}\\
&=2-2\sqrt{1-x},\\
\end{align}$$
$$\implies f{\left(x\right)}=\frac{\left(1-\sqrt{1-x}\right)^{2}}{x}=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x}}{1+\sqrt{1-x}}.$$
We can then write $\mathcal{S}$ as a double integral in the following way:
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{S}
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{\left(n+1\right)4^{n}}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{\left(n+1\right)4^{n}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\left(1-t\right)^{n}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\,\frac{\left(1+zt\right)^{n}-\left(1-zt\right)^{n}}{zt}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{\left(n+1\right)4^{n}}\cdot\frac{\left(1-t\right)^{n}\left(1+zt\right)^{n}-\left(1-t\right)^{n}\left(1-zt\right)^{n}}{zt}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\,\frac{f{\left(\left(1-t\right)\left(1+zt\right)\right)}-f{\left(\left(1-t\right)\left(1-zt\right)\right)}}{zt}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\,\frac{1}{zt}\left[\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\left(1-t\right)\left(1+zt\right)}}{1+\sqrt{1-\left(1-t\right)\left(1+zt\right)}}-\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\left(1-t\right)\left(1-zt\right)}}{1+\sqrt{1-\left(1-t\right)\left(1-zt\right)}}\right].\\
\end{align}$$
We can further reduce $\mathcal{S}$ to a single-variable integral as follows:
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{S}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\,\frac{1}{zt}\left[\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\left(1-t\right)\left(1+zt\right)}}{1+\sqrt{1-\left(1-t\right)\left(1+zt\right)}}-\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\left(1-t\right)\left(1-zt\right)}}{1+\sqrt{1-\left(1-t\right)\left(1-zt\right)}}\right]\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\,\frac{1}{tz}\left[\frac{1-\sqrt{t\left(1-\left(1-t\right)z\right)}}{1+\sqrt{t\left(1-\left(1-t\right)z\right)}}-\frac{1-\sqrt{t\left(1+\left(1-t\right)z\right)}}{1+\sqrt{t\left(1+\left(1-t\right)z\right)}}\right]\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{1-t}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{ty}\left[\frac{1-\sqrt{t\left(1-y\right)}}{1+\sqrt{t\left(1-y\right)}}-\frac{1-\sqrt{t\left(1+y\right)}}{1+\sqrt{t\left(1+y\right)}}\right];~~~\small{\left[\left(1-t\right)z=y\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{1-y}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{yt}\left[\frac{1-\sqrt{t\left(1-y\right)}}{1+\sqrt{t\left(1-y\right)}}-\frac{1-\sqrt{t\left(1+y\right)}}{1+\sqrt{t\left(1+y\right)}}\right]\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-y}}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2}{yu}\left[\frac{1-u\sqrt{1-y}}{1+u\sqrt{1-y}}-\frac{1-u\sqrt{1+y}}{1+u\sqrt{1+y}}\right];~~~\small{\left[\sqrt{t}=u\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{4}{y}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-y}}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{1}{2u}\left[\frac{1-u\sqrt{1-y}}{1+u\sqrt{1-y}}-\frac{1-u\sqrt{1+y}}{1+u\sqrt{1+y}}\right]\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{4}{y}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-y}}\mathrm{d}u\,\left[\frac{\sqrt{1+y}}{1+u\sqrt{1+y}}-\frac{\sqrt{1-y}}{1+u\sqrt{1-y}}\right]\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{4}{y}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-y}}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{d}{du}\ln{\left(\frac{1+u\sqrt{1+y}}{1+u\sqrt{1-y}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{4}{y}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}{2-y}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$
Then,
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{S}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{4}{y}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}{2-y}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{4}{y}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\left(1+y\right)\sqrt{\frac{1-y}{1+y}}}{2-y}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2}{\left(1+t\right)^{2}}\cdot\frac{4}{\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\left(\frac{2}{1+t}\right)\sqrt{t}}{2-\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)}\right)};~~~\small{\left[y=\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{8}{1-t^{2}}\ln{\left(\frac{(1+t)+2\sqrt{t}}{2(1+t)-\left(1-t\right)}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{8}{1-t^{2}}\ln{\left(\frac{1+t+2\sqrt{t}}{1+3t}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{16u}{1-u^{4}}\ln{\left(\frac{1+2u+u^{2}}{1+3u^{2}}\right)};~~~\small{\left[\sqrt{t}=u\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{\left(1+x\right)^{2}}\cdot\frac{2\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\left(1+x\right)^{4}}{x\left(1+x^{2}\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{1}{1-x+x^{2}}\right)};~~~\small{\left[u=\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{4\left(1-x^{2}\right)}{x\left(1+x^{2}\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{1}{1-x+x^{2}}\right)}\\
&=4\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[\frac{1}{x}-\frac{2x}{1+x^{2}}\right]\ln{\left(\frac{1}{1-x+x^{2}}\right)}\\
&=4\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{x}\ln{\left(\frac{1}{1-x+x^{2}}\right)}-4\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2x}{1+x^{2}}\ln{\left(\frac{1}{1-x+x^{2}}\right)}\\
&=4\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{x}\ln{\left(\frac{1+x}{1+x^{3}}\right)}+4\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2x\ln{\left(1-x+x^{2}\right)}}{1+x^{2}}\\
&=4\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+x\right)}}{x}-4\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+x^{3}\right)}}{x}+4\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2x\ln{\left(1-x+x^{2}\right)}}{1+x^{2}}\\
&=4\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+x\right)}}{x}-4\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+u\right)}}{3u};~~~\small{\left[x^{3}=u\right]}\\
&~~~~~+4\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2x\ln{\left(1-x+x^{2}\right)}}{1+x^{2}}\\
&=\frac83\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+x\right)}}{x}+4\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2x\ln{\left(1-x+x^{2}\right)}}{1+x^{2}}\\
&=\frac43\zeta{\left(2\right)}+4\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2x\ln{\left(1-x+x^{2}\right)}}{1+x^{2}}.\\
\end{align}$$

The integral we need can be evaluated using Feynman's method of differentiating under the integral sign.
Define the function $\mathcal{I}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ via the definite integral
$$\mathcal{I}{\left(\alpha\right)}:=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2x\ln{\left(x^{2}-2x\cos{\left(\alpha\right)}+1\right)}}{x^{2}+1}.$$
By the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have
$$\mathcal{I}{\left(\alpha\right)}-\mathcal{I}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}=\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\alpha}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\mathcal{I}^{\prime}{\left(\varphi\right)};~~~\small{0<\alpha<\pi}.$$
Note that
$$\mathcal{I}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}=\frac12\ln^{2}{\left(2\right)}.$$
For $\alpha\in(0,\pi)\land\alpha\neq\frac{\pi}{2}$, we find
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(\alpha\right)}
&=\mathcal{I}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\alpha}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\mathcal{I}^{\prime}{\left(\varphi\right)}\\
&=\mathcal{I}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\alpha}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{d}{d\varphi}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2x\ln{\left(x^{2}-2x\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}+1\right)}}{x^{2}+1}\\
&=\mathcal{I}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\alpha}\mathrm{d}\varphi\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\partial}{\partial\varphi}\frac{2x\ln{\left(x^{2}-2x\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}+1\right)}}{x^{2}+1}\\
&=\mathcal{I}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\alpha}\mathrm{d}\varphi\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{4x^{2}\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}}{\left(x^{2}+1\right)\left[x^{2}-2x\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}+1\right]}\\
&=\mathcal{I}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\alpha}\mathrm{d}\varphi\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\tan{\left(\varphi\right)}\left[\frac{2x}{x^{2}-2x\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}+1}-\frac{2x}{x^{2}+1}\right]\\
&=\mathcal{I}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\alpha}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\tan{\left(\varphi\right)}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[\frac{2x-2\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}}{x^{2}-2x\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}+1}-\frac{2x}{x^{2}+1}+\frac{2\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}}{x^{2}-2x\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}+1}\right]\\
&=\mathcal{I}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\alpha}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\tan{\left(\varphi\right)}\left[\ln{\left(1-\cos{\left(\alpha\right)}\right)}+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}}{x^{2}-2x\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}+1}\right]\\
&=\mathcal{I}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\alpha}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\left[\tan{\left(\varphi\right)}\ln{\left(1-\cos{\left(\alpha\right)}\right)}+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}}{x^{2}-2x\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}+1}\right]\\
&=\mathcal{I}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\alpha}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\left[\tan{\left(\varphi\right)}\ln{\left(1-\cos{\left(\alpha\right)}\right)}+\left(\pi-\varphi\right)\right]\\
&=\mathcal{I}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}+\left[\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\alpha}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\left(\pi-\varphi\right)+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\alpha}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\tan{\left(\varphi\right)}\ln{\left(1-\cos{\left(\alpha\right)}\right)}\right]\\
&=\mathcal{I}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}+\left[\frac{\pi^{2}}{8}-\frac12\left(\pi-\alpha\right)^{2}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\cos{\left(\alpha\right)}\right)}\right]\\
&=\frac12\ln^{2}{\left(2\right)}+\frac{\pi^{2}}{8}-\frac12\left(\pi-\alpha\right)^{2}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\cos{\left(\alpha\right)}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$
In particular, we can use the special value of the dilogarithm at $\frac12$ to obtain the value of $\mathcal{I}$ at $\frac{\pi}{3}$:
$$\mathcal{I}{\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2x\ln{\left(x^{2}-x+1\right)}}{x^{2}+1}=-\frac{\pi^{2}}{72}=-\frac{1}{12}\zeta{\left(2\right)}.$$

Hence,
$$\mathcal{S}=\frac43\zeta{\left(2\right)}+4\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2x\ln{\left(1-x+x^{2}\right)}}{1+x^{2}}=\zeta{\left(2\right)}.\blacksquare$$

Truly great work, I appreciate it, thank you. Now this last integral seems a doable one, so I will attempt it myself as soon as I have the possibility.

@Zima Integral completed! ;)

Consider
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)4^{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{2n}{n-k}\frac{z^{k}}{k^{2}}.
$$
Assume $\binom{n}{k}=0$ for $k\ge n$, the upper bound for $k$ can be set to $\infty$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
    f(z)&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{k}}{k^{2}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n-k} \frac{1}{(n+1)4^{n}} \\
    &=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{k}}{k^{2}}\int_{0}^{1} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n-k} \frac{x^{n}}{4^{n}} dx \\
    &=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{k}}{k^{2}}\int_{0}^{1}\left( \frac{x}{\big(1+\sqrt{1-x}\big)^{2}} \right)^{k}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x}}  \\
    &=4\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{k}}{k^{2}}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{y^{k}}{(1+y)^{2}} dy \\
    &=4\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\operatorname{Li}_{2}(yz) }{(1+y)^{2}}dy \\
    &=-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}(z)-4\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(1-yz)}{y(1+y)}dy  \\
\end{align*}
where $y=\frac{4x}{(1+x)^{2}}$ and the expansion
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n-k} \frac{x^{n}}{4^{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}\left( \frac{x}{\big(1+\sqrt{1-x}\big)^{2}} \right)^{k}
$$
is used. Now the desired sum is
$$
f(1)-f(-1)=-\frac{\pi^{2}}{2}+4\int_{0}^{1} \log\left( \frac{1+y}{1-y} \right) \frac{dy}{y(1+y)}=\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}.
$$

How would you evaluate the integral?

@ТymaGaidash It is relatively trivial, perhaps a $t=\frac{1+y}{1-y}$ sub.

Just a few numbers.
If $$b_n=\frac{a_n}{(n+1)\,4^n}$$ is the summand, then asymptotically
$$\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} \sim  1-\frac {\log(n)} {5n}$$ explains the "speed" of convergence.
Computing a few partial sums
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & \sum_{n=1}^{k} b_n \\ 
 1000 & 1.55794488204578 \\
 2000 & 1.58319742179975 \\
 3000 & 1.59444620978238 \\
 4000 & 1.60116937267002 \\
 5000 & 1.60576491618272 \\
 6000 & 1.60916104198538 \\
 7000 & 1.61180274633008 \\
 8000 & 1.61393358040659 \\
 9000 & 1.61569953600208 \\ 
10000 & 1.61719415514243 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
A long way to go before even approaching $\zeta(2)$.
Edit
It is worth to notice that, from the table, assuming that the result is $\zeta(2)$, a quick and dirty linear regression gives $(R^2=0.999999039)$
$$k\,\sum_{n=1}^{k} b_n \sim 510 + \zeta(2) \, k -84\log(k)$$

This might be one of the slowest converging sums I ever encountered. It is even slower than Madhava, which requires 5000 terms for 4 correct decimal places. Here with 10000 we still have just  one...

@Zima. Mathematice. Why don't you registed at Mathematica Cloud ? it is free

If master integrator Claude Leibovici cannot get to a closed form proof, definitely I cannot.
But I am providing this answer, just for the sake of expressing it in a slightly faster converging form.
First of all, I extracted the terms containing $\frac{1}{1^{2}}$,$\frac{1}{3^{2}}$,$\frac{1}{5^{2}}$,$\frac{1}{7^{2}}$ ... (noting that even terms disappear due to the numerator of $a_{n}$).
With this, we get expressions of the following type:
$$\frac{2}{1^{2}} \left [ \frac{\binom{2}{0}}{2 . 4} + \frac{\binom{4}{1}}{3 . 4^{2}} + \frac{\binom{6}{2}}{4 . 4^{3}} + ...\right ]$$
$$+ \frac{2}{3^{2}} \left [ \frac{\binom{6}{0}}{4 . 4^{3}} + \frac{\binom{8}{1}}{5 . 4^{4}} + \frac{\binom{10}{2}}{6 . 4^{5}} + ...\right ]$$
$$+ \frac{2}{5^{2}} \left [  ...\right ]$$
$$+ \frac{2}{7^{2}} \left [  ...\right ]$$
The final sum can be expressed as
$$S = \sum b_{n} = \sum\limits_{n=odd}\frac{2}{n^{2}} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\binom{2k+2n-2}{k-1}}{(k+n)4^{k+n-1}}$$
Mathematica does find a generalized closed form of $b_{n}$ in the form HyperGeometricPFQ and Gamma functions. It cannot close $S$ and I have no idea what to do with those HyperGeometricPFQ functions. So the next thing I did is to numerically express $b_{n}$. For the first few terms, you can see the following result for $b_{n}$ and partial sum $S_{n}$.
$$b_{1} = -4 + \frac{8 \log(2)}{1} ; S_{1} = 1.54518$$
$$b_{3} = -\frac{16}{9} + \frac{8 \log(2)}{3} ; S_{3} = 1.61579$$
$$b_{5} = -\frac{82}{75} + \frac{8 \log(2)}{5} ; S_{5} = 1.63149$$
$$b_{7} = -\frac{578}{735} + \frac{8 \log(2)}{7} ; S_{7} = 1.63727$$
$$b_{9} = -\frac{1739}{2835} + \frac{8 \log(2)}{9} ; S_{9} = 1.63999$$
$$b_{11} = -\frac{19157}{38115} + \frac{8 \log(2)}{11} ; S_{11} = 1.64149$$
$$b_{13} = -\frac{249251}{585585} + \frac{8 \log(2)}{13} ; S_{13} = 1.6424$$
And $\zeta(2) =~ 1.64493$.
Note: The terms $\sum\limits_{n = odd} \frac{8 \log(2)}{n}$ diverges, so I did not make any further attempts to club those terms "vertically".
